# If condition with curly brackets is not working correctly in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

This works:

```
if($('div.login-part').is(':empty'))
        $('div.login-part').append('<p>Login</p>');
```

But this is not:

```
if($('div.login-part').is(':empty')) 
{
        $('div.login-part').append('<p>Login</p>');
            $('div.login-part').append('<p>Welcome!</p>');
            $('div.login-part').append('<p>What is your name?</p>');
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is a JavaScript question. jQuery isn't a language, it's a library.

Comment: I was thinking that it has something to do with append() which is a method from jQuery library.

Comment: It has nothing to do, the syntax is correct. Whatever is wrong it is not in those lines, so bad guess. Instead of guessing, you should debug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/avSDa/10/

Please check closing quotes in your code; Since I know the background of this question from previous early reply `:)`

Demo should help you,

Hope this helps, cheers

**code**

```
// FOR REGISTRATION
$('span.logreg.reg').click(function() {

    if ($('div.login-part').is(':empty')) {
        $('div.login-part').append('<p>Login</p>');
        $('div.login-part').append('<p>Welcome!</p>');
        $('div.login-part').append('<p>What is your name?</p>');
    }
});
```

Comment: @Eric I know the previous question which lead to this question hence I have a demo as well `:)`

Comment: So the problem with the OPs code is in a bit they haven't given us?

Comment: @Eric not sure BUt I really won't `down vote` a newbie `:)` as s/he puts effort to the question, hence just helping op, anyhoo your answer is good as well, cheers for comments though

Comment: Your code appears to be identical to the OPs. I'm not sure what you fixed.

Comment: @Eric it always worked like you replied, will different syntax, I gave a full demo to double check the full syntax! Quote your post "That should work fine. " but I have lil background hence I can see it can be syntax error, `:)` can be a valid cause.

Comment: Just hinting, this way of writing JS Code is BAD! See the answer with most votes, this one IS better - even if it accomplishes the same.

Comment: @Sam Yes I could have written chained function etc, I knw man `:)` I reckon I am bit clued up, but the **post below** already covered all the options, dint wanted to steal anyone's stuff. I appreciate your comment! cheers! **some good reads** http://www.braindonor.net/blog/jquery-best-practices-part-1-managing-scope/406/ **or** http://www.braindonor.net/blog/thebraindonors-jquery-best-practices-part-2-chaining/427/

Comment: Oh i am pretty damn sure you know that thing. This was more directed towards the OP, as he was writing it just like you replied. Given your numbers, i can only assume you know the drill ;)

Comment: Usually I share your idea of "keep it simple for the sake of newbies" but here you can simply put `$('div.login-part')` into local variable and use it as having jQuery search for that element four times is just wrong. It's like writing `var x = 1; x = 2; x = 3; x = 5;` just to put 5 into x. It won't steal anything from anyone, just guide the OP to write bit better code.

Comment: @Sam +1; cheers bruv, lol time at my part of world to sleep now, nice to see you around! `:)`

Comment: @ShadowWizard +1; Thanks bruv! `:)` time for me to dose off now I reckon, Thank-you for comment though :)

Answer (score 5):

That should work fine. You can, however, make your code more efficient by not running the selector multiple times:

```
var login = $('div.login-part')
if(login.is(':empty')) {
    login.append('<p>Login</p>');
    login.append('<p>Welcome!</p>');
    login.append('<p>What is your name?</p>');
}
```

You can even reduce that to:

```
$('div.login-part:empty')
    .append('<p>Login</p>')
    .append('<p>Welcome!</p>')
    .append('<p>What is your name?</p>');
```

Or even:

```
$('div.login-part:empty').append(
    '<p>Login</p>',
    '<p>Welcome!</p>',
    '<p>What is your name?</p>'
);
```

Comment: +1 for this answer, as this saves recourses, too. Always safe your selectors into variables to improve script efficiency

Comment: @Sam: Or factor out using the selection in more than one statement - CHAIN ALL THE THINGS.